# Convert json data to variable in php

Tags: php, json

Hello I am try to get this last data from JSON i decode it make var_dump and this is the output object

`(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["base"]=> string(3) "BGN" ["date"]=> string(10) "2017-05-30" ["rates"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["EUR"]=> float(0.5113) } }`

I need this 0.5113 and after that to make a calculations with it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The value `0.5113` is in the EUR property of an object in the `rates` property of your root object:

```
$obj->rates->EUR === 0.5113
```